# What are the similarities/differences between the four Madhabs? Charts?

Tags: sunni, madhhab

I'm very new to the studies of Islam so I apologize if my question is very basic.

It is my understanding that madhab is a term to describe a school of thought AND that in general, there are four schools of thoughts: Sunni, Shia, Ibadi, and   Amman Message.

Is there a chart/venn diagram that compares/contrasts these four schools of thoughts?

What is the importance of all these differences and similarities?

Thanks for your help on my pursuit to understand more about Islam.

Comment: What is the Amman Message, never heard of it?

Comment: Maybe this is helpful http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/27902/how-many-muslims-in-the-world-are-there-in-moderate-progressive-categories

Comment: Thank you so much! It is certainly very thorough and chalk full of info! I'll be printing it out and studying it intently! But I'm not sure if it answers about the four madhab (Maybe it does, and I just don't have enough background to know so). I read of the Amman Message when I googled "madhab" -- but maybe it's not mainstream? Not sure! Thank you so much for this info though!!!